# gfortran: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 signal terminated program f951

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

I am working with fortran on my MAC. Everything was working, but when I started to use brew to install for example python or other programs, everything started to crash, because I think several files has been moved from their original positions and probably some libraries were mixed. I read on Internet how to solve my errors, but I was unable to do that. I will post below the error I find, when I launch `gfortran`

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.23.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17/10.2.0/f951
  Reason: image not found
gfortran: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 signal terminated program f951
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues> for instructions.
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling gfortran

Comment: I have tried to reinstall gfortran and gcc, since they are connected, but never changes!

Comment: This happens also for me (for Gnuplot etc), and I usually make a symbolic link for the missing dylib file (e.g. cd /usr/local/opt/isl/lib, and ln -s <newer one> libisl.23.dylib) But not sure it if works for the latest MacOS or gfortran...

Comment: I was finally able to solve such issue. As @roygvib proposed the errors comes from the fact that gfortran is present, but the symbolic link to the gfortran library is not present. The way to solve such an issue on MAC can be done, by first launching `brew doctor`. This permits to see where there are missing links and can guide you better where the error is located. Then I have done `brew unlink`, `brew instal gcc` and then `brew link`. This is a way to stabilize again the missing links. I suggest also to have a look at Homebrew GitHub forum, which can give more targeted answers.

Comment: @VDF I see .. I will try "brew doctor" etc from now on (when I have a similar problem :) Btw, I believe it would be very useful if you put your comment above as an Answer (and accept it later), so that other people can get the info more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Normally on MAC when you try to install other programs, like python, ipython, or others, it can happen that your program like gfortran (connected with gcc) cannot work anymore, giving an error message as the one specified by me above. This tells you that the libraries of gfortran have been not found. Premising that I am not expert of programming, I would suggest to solve similar issues by  typing first `brew doctor`, which permits you to see which kinds of error are present. In my case it was spotted that the link to the gfortran library was not connected. So I have done `brew unlink`, `brew instal gcc` and then `brew link`. This entails that the missing link is again stabilized. I suggest also to have a look at Homebrew GitHub forum (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues), which can give more targeted answers